# Spring batch best practice regarding data between steps

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-batch

We have an old codebase which i think can be improved a lot by selecting a good batch processing framework.

I've started experimenting with Spring batch and decided (after reading docs, multiple books and forums about it) that the best way to get a feel of it is to actually use it, so i've redeveloped some of our existing apps to Spring Batch.

Here is the simple app i've redeveloped:

- Read lines from a table and parse lines to a POJO
- If a give criteria is met, ignore the item from the list
- Write a file from the parsed list
- Upload the file to an FTP
- Mark elements of the parsed list as processed in the db if the FTP upload is successful

Now, what i've done is i've created a single job with 3 steps:

Step1 is: read lines to POJO(reader, jdbc based in this case), exclude items (processor), write to File (writer). Easy. :)

Step2: tasklet to upload to FTP

Step3: now, this is where i'm in trouble. I need to reused the POJO list from Step1.

My understanding is that i have two options:

**1)** either use the StepExecutionContext, save the List there and a ExecutionContextPromotionListener implementation to pass the list between Step1 and Step2 and Step2 and Step3.

or

**2)** I use the same reader and processor and use a different writer this time.

I don't really like either approach

1) seems messy and i've read in multiple places that it is not a good practice to put something bigger in this context (my list would hold 5-10000 objects)

2) Seems a waste of resource and again, a bad practice. In this scenario, i could get away with it, but in the case of a more complex reader/processor, it would be a quite bad duplication of work.

What is the best way to do what i'm looking to do?
Am i using Spring Batch correctly here?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would structure the job steps.

1. Read: DB
   Write: File1
2. Read: File1
   Process: SkipFilter
   Write: File2
3. FTP using System Command Tasklet
4. Read: File1 or File2
   Write: DB

I added a step to protect against the DB changing while downstream steps were performed.

Comment: Yes, this is probably better than my two options. :) Stil, however, i need to iterate through a file i've created before, so it is going to be slower and a bit wasteful. Do you think i'm approaching Spring batch correctly at all?

Comment: One more thing: i would not use System Command Tasklet, that makes my code dependent on the server it is running on, i would write my own Tasklet to handle FTP uploads. But this is just a detail :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading the  "Spring Batch Essientials" book and they had the idea to use "holder beans" to hold the data. Inject the bean to set and get data with it.

Comment: The only thing i need to work out is how to make this solution threadsafe. :)